# PowerShell and SharePoint 2010 web analytics reports – can this be done?

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-analytics

Does anyone have a script to pull user email addresses from SharePoint 2010 web analytics reports?
As part of preparation to move sites from SP2010 to SharePoint Online, we'd like to help our site owners by giving them a means to communicate changes to their site users. The 90 day web analytics report with unique users (firstname lastname) is a great start but it's a pain turning them into actionable email addresses.